# How to pull out values corresponding to a random selection and get the cumulative summation of them?

Tags: r, loops, dataframe

Let's say I have a data frame with two columns for now:

```
df<- data.frame(scores_set1=c(32,45,65,96,45,23,23,14),
scores_set2=c(32,40,60,98,21,23,21,63))
```

I want to randomly select some rows

```
selected_indeces<- sample(c(1:8), 4, replace = FALSE)
```

Now I want to add up the values of `selected_indeces` sequentially meaning that for first `selected_indeces` I just need the value of that specific row, for the second I want the second row value + the first selected value ... and for the nth index I want sum of all values selected already + the value nth row. So, first need a matrix to put the results in

```
   cumulative_loss<-matrix(rep(NA,8*2),nrow=8,ncol=2)
```

and then one loop for each column and another for each selected_index

```
for (s in 1:ncol(df)) #for each column
     {
    for (i in 1:length(selected_indeces)) #for each randomly selected index
      {
      if (i==1)
        {
       cumulative_loss[i,s]<- df[selected_indeces[i],s]
        }

      if (i > 1)
         {
    cumulative_loss[i,s]<- df[selected_indeces[i],s] +  
      df[selected_indeces[i-1],s]
    }
  }
}
```

The script works although It might be a naive way for doing such thing but the thing is that if (i=4) is only adds values of 4th and third selection while I want it to add first, second , third and fourth random selection and return it.

Comment: I'm guessing that all you really need is the name of the function that does this: `cumsum`. You should delete the question since it is many times over duplicated and it was really your job to do some searching. If you code is demonstrating some other phenomenon, then you should edit it to put forth an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a way to do this with `data.table` (taking into account your comment on @bgoldst's answer:

```
library(data.table); setDT(df)

#sample 4 elements of each column (i.e., every element of .SD), then cumsum them
df[ , lapply(.SD, function(x) cumsum(sample(x, 4)))]
```

---

If you want to use different indices for each column, I would pre-choose them first:

```
set.seed(1023)
idx <- lapply(integer(ncol(df)), function(...) sample(nrow(df), 4))
idx
# [[1]] #indices for column 1
# [1] 2 8 6 3
# 
# [[2]] #indices for column 2
# [1] 4 8 5 1
```

Then modify the above slightly:

```
df[ , lapply( seq_along(.SD), function(jj) cumsum(.SD[[jj]][ idx[[jj]] ]) )]
```

This is the craziest compendium of brackets/parentheses I've ever written in a functional line of code, so I guess it makes sense to break things down a bit:

- `seq_along` `.SD` to pick out the *index number* of each column, `jj`
- `.SD[[jj]]` selects the `j`th column, `idx[[jj]]` selects the indices for that column, `.SD[jj]][idx[jj]]]` picks the `idx[[jj]]` rows of the `j`th column; this is equivalent to `.SD[idx[jj], jj, with = FALSE]`
- Lastly, we `cumsum` the `length(idx[[jj]])` rows we chose for column `jj`.

Result:

```
#     V1  V2
# 1:  45  98
# 2:  59 161
# 3:  82 182
# 4: 147 214
```

Comment: This works perfectly given that my data table is huge and lappy is very fast. I wonder if I can keep track of selected rows. I mean i definitely need to save which rows sampled in each column. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: Thanks for your help Michael! I get the folowing error and am trying to debug it:                                                                                                                  Error in df[, lapply(seq_along(.SD), function(jj) cumsum(.SD[[jj]][idx[[jj]]]))] : 
  object of type 'closure' is not subsettable

Comment: @vahab now you've seen the danger in naming your data after a function (see `?df`). make sure you've actually got an object named `df`, or R will assume you mean the function.

Comment: That's true, Thanks for noticing it!

Comment: I tried to use already known indices (what you called idx above) into the line: df[ , lapply(.SD, function(x) cumsum(sample(x, 4)))]. But no success, any idea how should this line of code change in order to get cumsum for known selected rows?

Comment: There is no error @MichaelChirico. I need to access the selected rows for each column.

Comment: this  df[ , lapply(seq_along(.SD), function(jj) cumsum(.SD[[jj]][idx[[jj]]]))] returns cumsum values correctly but I need to have the selected samples as well (i.e. their row number)

Comment: That's what I asked in the first place, Sorry if I was not clear though! I wanted to make sure the same indices are being used for cumsum calculation. And obviously it is what is happening which is great!

Answer (score 3):

Conveniently, [`cumsum()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/cumsum.html) works on data.frames directly, in which case it runs on each column independently. Thus we can index out the selected rows of `df` with an index operation and pass the result directly to `cumsum()` to get the required output:

```
set.seed(0L);
sel <- sample(1:8,4L);
sel;
## [1] 8 2 3 6
df[sel,];
##   scores_set1 scores_set2
## 8          14          63
## 2          45          40
## 3          65          60
## 6          23          23
cumsum(df[sel,]);
##   scores_set1 scores_set2
## 8          14          63
## 2          59         103
## 3         124         163
## 6         147         186
```

---

To select different indexes for each column, we can use `apply()`:

```
set.seed(0L);
apply(df,2L,function(col) cumsum(col[sample(1:8,4L)]));
##      scores_set1 scores_set2
## [1,]          14          63
## [2,]          59         103
## [3,]         124         126
## [4,]         147         147
```

If you want to compute the indexes in advance, it becomes slightly trickier. Here's one way of doing it:

```
set.seed(0L);
sels <- replicate(2L,sample(1:8,4L)); sels;
##      [,1] [,2]
## [1,]    8    8
## [2,]    2    2
## [3,]    3    6
## [4,]    6    5
sapply(seq_len(ncol(df)),function(ci) cumsum(df[[ci]][sels[,ci]]));
##      [,1] [,2]
## [1,]   14   63
## [2,]   59  103
## [3,]  124  126
## [4,]  147  147
```

Comment: Excellent! Now it is selecting same rows in each column, What if I want different selection for each column so it is not biased.

Comment: I always hate `apply`... how about maybe `Reduce(cbind.data.frame, lapply(df, function(jj) cumsum(sample(jj, 4))))`? Output has junk for column names but could do...

Answer (score 0):

With `dplyr`, if we want to `sample` each column separately and do the `cumsum`, we can use `mutate_each` and then select the first 4 with `head`.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   mutate_each(funs(cumsum(sample(.)))) %>%
   head(.,4)
```

---

If the `sample` needs to be for the whole dataset

```
df %>%
   slice(sample(row_number(), 4)) %>%
   mutate_each(funs(cumsum))
```

Comment: why sample and evaluate on the whole vector and only to toss (in all likelihood) most of it?

Comment: @MichaelChirico  Because the `dplyr` `summarise_each` or `mutate_each` won't allow for doing it with different number than the nrow.  Possible option is `do`, which would be slow

Comment: I'm obviously a `dplyr` naif, `cumsum(sample(., 4))` doesn't work? don't have it installed on current machine

Comment: @MichaelChirico  I tried that previously and it didn't work because the number of elements are different.